# Youtube video doesn't stop in IE if I hide its parent div

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, youtube, youtube-api

So for example I have a structure like this:

**Javascript**

```
function toggle(id){
    var element = document.getElementById("id");

    if(element.style.display != 'block'){
        element.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="toggle('holder')">Toggle Video</div>

<div id="holder" style="display:none">
   <object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/A_hp2ubJaNo?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/A_hp2ubJaNo?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed></object>
</div>
```

When I click `Toggle Video` the video `shows up` and `starts playing`, when I click it again the video `hides out` but the video is **`still playing`** in Internet Explorer!

Please **do not** post any answers with jQuery or any library, only pure Javascript,  thanks !

Comment: Can you show `toggle()`? I suppose it toggles `element.style.display`, but for completeness sake...

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggling the CSS `display` property is not a reliable way of killing Flash. As you have discovered, the behaviour is different between browsers. You'd be better off clipping the element from the DOM using `domElement.`[`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode)`.`[`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild)`(domElement)`

Comment: Maybe, but works in all browsers, except IE and that's the problem :P

Answer (score 1):

In the case of IE7, it appears that the Youtube's object doesn't "unload" itself when it's hidden compared to IE8 or FF 3.6. For example, in IE8 if the object is hidden the function *youtubeobject.stopVideo* is undefined, but in IE7 it's still exists.

I think a more elegant solution is to check to see if the "stopVideo" function exists in the Youtube object, and then call it.

```
function toggle(id){
    var element = document.getElementById("id");

    if(element.style.display != 'block'){
        element.style.display = 'none';
        var ytobject = document.getElementById("youtubeplayerid");
        if(ytobject.stopVideo) {
            ytobject.stopVideo();
        }
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'block';
        var element = document.getElementById("youtubeplayerid");
        if(ytobject.playVideo) {
            ytobject.playVideo();
        }
    }
}
```